# What would cause macro mode to be locked out on my Panasonic Lumix DMC camera?

Tags: troubleshooting, macro, camera-settings, panasonic-lumix

I have a Panasonic Lumix DMC TZ55. Suddenly, I can't use the macro on my camera. On the monitor it says "lock" with an arrow under it. How do I unlock it? What is causing the macro to cease working?

Comment: Some cameras have a button lock feature to prevent accidental setting changes.  Look in your camera manual for how to enable/disable it.